# create dropdowns in a loop using angularjs with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a number of dropdowns in a **loop** using angularjs (dropdown for every product list)

criteria:
 - It should not create empty option

My problem is empty option is creating, I couldn't set option reference with ng-model for all dropdowns, please help

the dropdown for color property

json like:

```
function pList($scope){  
    $scope.prodList = {"products":    [{"pInfo":  {
    "color" : [{
        "name" : "red",
        "index" : "0",
        "url": "plain_50.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name" : "blue",
        "index" : "1",
         "url": "plain_20.jpg"
    }]  
 }},{"pInfo":  {
    "color" : [{
        "name" : "orange",
        "index" : "0",
         "url": "plain_10.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name" : "yellow",
        "index" : "1",
        "url": "plain_40.jpg"
    }]  
 }}
 ]
 }
    $scope.clrChange = function(val){
            console.log(val);           
    }
  }

  <article ng-repeat="prod in prodList.products" ng-init="myColor=$index">
  <select ng-model="myColor" ng-change="clrChange(myColor)">
    <option value="">select color</option>
    <option ng-repeat="color in prod.pInfo.color">{{color.name}}</option>
  </select>
</article>
```

Comment: where is your code? `"I need"` is not a question and without code we can only guuess at what you are doing

Comment: Could you provide a Plunkr or paste the code in your question description? There really isn't enough information in your question presently for anyone to help you

Comment: show the code you are trying to use. Also, the added json is invalid, you can't duplicate properties within same object

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose the JSON data coming from database is like this.
It consists of two JSON object in list. 
Also below you can see  HTML Code to traverse the each JSON object in list.

```
 {
           "requirement":[
              {
                 "contributor":"dsfs",
                 "creator":"dsfsd",
                 "description":"SDFDf",

              },
              {
                 "contributor":"rg",
                 "creator":"regre",
                 "description":"REGREg",

              }
           ]
        }




  <table style="width: 300px">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">contributor</th>
                <th colspan="1">creator</th>
                <th colspan="1">description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat = 'req in requirement.list'>
                <td colspan = "1"><input type="text" ng-readonly="true" ng-model="req.contributor"></td>
                <td colspan = "1"><input type="text" ng-readonly="true" ng-model="req.creator"></td>
                <td colspan = "1"><input type="text" ng-readonly="true" ng-model="req.description"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Do comment if this is what you were looking for. Thanks...:)

Also, elaborate more what is your problem if i haven't got you clearly...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<article ng-repeat="prod in prodList.products">
    <select ng-model="prod.color" ng-options="color.name for color in prod.pInfo.color" ng-change="clrChange(prod.color)">
        <option value="">select color</option>
    </select>
</article>
```

**[Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hLIsgJjXGvtyorDY7iDZ?p=preview)**

Comment: no, I need to show img for color in option list so I preferred to use ng-repeat. thanks for your reply